# can not attach mdf file of suspect database

Tags: sql-server, attachment

i have a suspect database so i did :

```
EXEC sp_resetstatus [Data_MARIEM];

ALTER DATABASE [Data_MARIEM] SET EMERGENCY;
```

after that i detach the database. now i can't attach it again.

Comment: where is the mdf file please???

Comment: If all you did was to detach the database, the mdf file should be in the same location it was previously.

Comment: And when you say "can't attach it again", what happens if you try?